# Write contents of a vtkPolyData object to a Custom file format

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vtk

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 with VTK version 5.1.

So i've got a custom file format i've generated from a 3d model, which stores all my points and polygons for N 3d objects. In C++ i've got a program which reads in all of the points into an instance of vtkPoints, reads all of the polygons into an instance of vtkCellArray, then puts both of these into a vtkPolyData. Once i've got the vtkPolyData filled, I want to access all of the data i've just read in, manually, and write it back to a new file in my custom format in order to verify that the import and export procedures are reciprocating.

It would be most beneficial if i could get a vector of 3-element tuples which represents the points, and then a vector of q-dimensional tuples which have differing length but represent each vertex in sequence that makes up a polygon.

I saw that there's a GetPointData() function and a GetPolys() function, but that's where I get stuck. I don't have a reliable way to find out the size of the array it gave me a pointer to, and that is one of the criteria I want to verify. I'm sure there's a simple way to access the points, and the polys, but if someone could give an example of how to iterate through all of them, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a vtk user, but take a look at vtkFieldData (http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkFieldData.html). vtkPointData inherits from that. There is a method called GetArray which returns a vtkDataArray. GetNumberOfTuples could be used to loop thru the tuples.

Comment: The documentation I saw read that GetNumberOfTuples() is unreliable when working with a vtkCellArray or vtkPoints. That it may yield 'unexpected results'. I found this to be accurate.

Comment: vtkPoints has a GetNumberOfPoints that I've never found to be inaccurate.